# Optimizing 3d point hash function

Tags: python, optimization, hash

I have a 3-dimensional point class whose hash function, according to the profiler, would be a good place to do some optimizing. Right now, I'm just passing a tuple of the coordinates to the built-in hash function:

```
def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y, self.z))
```

How can I make this faster? I'm assuming constructing a tuple each time isn't good. The coordinates are real-valued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a tuple instead of your own class will be much faster.

If you really want to write p.x instead of p[0] then you can make your class a subclass of tuple and have accessors. It will still be much faster than implementing your own tuple.

```
class Point3d(tuple):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self[2]
```

Comment: I did some arbitrary tests with CPython. Using a pre-generated tuple like this halved my hashing time, bit shifting almost doubled it.

Comment: Why is this better than a named tuple?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) instead of your own class.